# Doctrine 2 SUM() equivalent helper?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm, sum

Strange, there is no SUM() equivalent in Doctrine2 helpers? There is max, min, count... am i blind?

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->avg('u.age')
public function avg($x); // Returns Expr\Func

// Example - $qb->expr()->max('u.age')
public function max($x); // Returns Expr\Func

// Example - $qb->expr()->min('u.age')
public function min($x); // Returns Expr\Func

// Example - $qb->expr()->abs('u.currentBalance')
public function abs($x); // Returns Expr\Func

// Example - $qb->expr()->sqrt('u.currentBalance')
public function sqrt($x); // Returns Expr\Func

// Example - $qb->expr()->count('u.firstname')
public function count($x); // Returns Expr\Func
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There does not appear to be a `sum()` helper. You can still use `SUM` in QueryBuilder; e.g:

```php
$qb->add('select', 'SUM(u.id)')
   ->add('from', 'User u')
```

Comment: +1 It's just under the `/** Arithmetic objects **/` section instead of with the rest of the aggregation operators, which is probably why OP missed it.

Comment: I'm talking about SUM aggregate function, THIS IS arithmetic function like division, subtract. -1

Comment: Answer accepted since it seems true - no `SUM()` aggregate helper in Doctrine2. So sad. Cant' figure out why - maybe because is missing in sqlite? Dunno...