# How to sum in dql?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I got sql like this:

```
Select sum(salary) from employees
```

I want to  write in dql but  can't.
In dql guide, they said:

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->sum('u.id', '2') => u.id + 2
public function sum($x, $y); // Returns Expr\Math instance
```

from [SUM in query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)
Then how to  sum a column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine 2 SUM() equivalent helper?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719293/doctrine-2-sum-equivalent-helper)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. but why didn't google show me that link??? Thanks alot.